# GM_openInTab: Permission denied to access property

Tags: firefox, greasemonkey

I currently am trying to open a new blank window and insert some content to it dynamically.

The problem is that everything I try, it throws `Permission denied to access property '...'`.

I have read a lot of related questions about this problem, but most of them refers to same-origin problem.

I tried to use the following urls:

- "" (empty string)
- "#"
- "about:blank"

The first two options was to bypass the same-origin problem, but the third option would be perfect. Anyway, they doesn't work.

The tab opens well, but then I can't do anything with it.

```
var win = GM_openInTab("ANY OPTION ABOVE");

win.document; // throws 'Permission denied to access property "document"'
win.addEventListener; // throws 'Permission denied to access property "addEventListener"'
$(win); // throws Permission denied to access property 'nodeType'

and so on...
```

I haven't tested it in any other versions other than FX 35.0.1 and GM 2.3, so I am not sure if it has something to do with the release of [Greasemonkey 2.0](http://www.greasespot.net/2014/06/greasemonkey-20-release.html) and all that privileged sandbox stuff.

I also tried `window.open`... same problem, but it is understandable. I just thought `GM_openInTab` would be the solution.

What I do know is that I don't know how to manage the tab anymore. Please, help!

Ps.: Yes, I have `@grant GM_openInTab` in the metadata block.

Answer (score 0):

Add the new page to `@include` and then do something like

```
// @include     http://stackoverflow.com
// @grant       GM_addStyle
// ==/UserScript==

if(window.location==='http://stackoverflow.com'){
//do whatever
}
```

That way no cross origin problems because you are actually running the script on the page in question.

That SHOULD work.